# AngularJs - One of the Table Column contains add button which in turn creates multiple text fields

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an requirement which I am trying from last two days, but still no success.

I have one table which contains, suppose 5 columns(DATA IP, PRIMARY IP, HOST NAME, HOST LOCATION, SECONDARY IP).

For one Data IP there could be multiple Secondary IP's. SO, I have created one table with all the text fields and for the ALT IP column I have created button for adding multiple text fields.
Till here I am able to create, now the problem is that I am not able to fetch the fields in my controller.

My HTML CODE:-

***
      -->

```
<br/> 
 <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <thead style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <tr style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">DATA IP</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">SERIAL NO</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">PUBLIC IP</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">HOST NAME</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">C NAME</th>                    
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">MANAGEMENT IP</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">DEVICE ROLE</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">ALT IP</th> 


                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="border: 1px solid black;">
                <tr style="border: 1px solid black;" ng-repeat="journeyObject in journeyObject  track by $index" >
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><input type="text" ng-model="journeyObject[$index].dataIp"/></td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><input type="text" ng-model="journeyObject[$index].serialNo"/></td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><input type="text" ng-model="journeyObject[$index].publicIp"/></td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><input type="text" ng-model="journeyObject[$index].hostName"/></td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><input type="text" ng-model="journeyObject[$index].cName"/></td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><input type="text" ng-model="journeyObject[$index].managementIp"/></td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><input type="text" ng-model="journeyObject[$index].deviceRole"/></td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
                <input type="text"   ng-repeat="altIp in journeyAltObject track by $index"  ng-model="journeyObject[$index].altIp"/>
                <input type='button' ng-click="addAltIps()" value='+' style="width:25px; height:20px" /></td>  


                </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>*** 

**ANGULAR CODE:-**

  $scope.journeyObject = [];
                    $scope.journeyAltObject=[];
                    var altObj1=[];
                     var obj1=[];
                     var obj2=[];
                     $scope.addAltIps = function(parent,index) {
 $scope.journeyAltObject.push({
                             altIp: ''
                         })
                         obj1.push($scope.journeyAltObject);
     }

                    $scope.addMoreCi = function(index){
  $scope.journeyObject.push({ 
                            dataIp: '', 
                            serialNo: '',
                            publicIp: '',
                            hostName: '', 
                            cName: '',
                            altIp:  $scope.journeyAltObject,
                            managementIp: '',
                            deviceRole: ''
                        });
                        obj2.push($scope.journeyObject);
                       console.log('$scope.journeyObject: '+$scope.journeyObject.dataIp);
                    }
                    $scope.addCI=function(form,journey){
                        for( var i in obj2){
                            console.log('journeyObject: '+obj2[i].dataIp);
                        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this should be really easy. Make an array to push all the dynamic values and then deal with the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple code. Which let's you add as many options as you want. Now, what you need is simply get those values from array where options/IPs(in your case) are pushed

For example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<body>

   <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <button ng-click="addOptions()">Add</button>
   <div ng-repeat="ip in options">

   <input type="text" ng-model="ip.ip"/>


   </div>
    {{options}}
    </div>

   <script>
     var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = "John Doe";

       $scope.options = [{"ip" : "192.168.1.1"}, {"ip" : "192.168.1.2"},{"ip" : "192.168.1.3"}];
$scope.addOptions = function(){
 $scope.options.push({"ip" : ""});
  };
});
  </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can save this code in file and run it for more clear understanding

Comment: I have tried this earlier, its working when the case is of <div> , but its not working when the case is of Table -ng-repeat and inside this also td - ng-repeat. Could u just try it with Table rows.